# Is it possible to create Flutter app automated testing?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing, automation, automated-tests

Is there any way to run an automated tests on the flutter app without writing code for test cases?

Answer (score 0):

If there was a way, nobody would be writing tests. So no, definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome tool called **Repeato** that is exactly what you are looking for. It helps test Flutter apps without coding, and it's available for Windows and Mac. All you need to do is connect your device and record the steps. For more information, you can check it out [here](https://www.repeato.app/).